# Meteor - Deny read?

Tags: meteor

How do you deny reads of a collection in meteor?

There is no allow/deny method for this and you can't do it in the collection publish filter since it only runs once.  I'm shocked, I thought it would just make sense that a template could render blank if you denied a read.

Meteor looks like it works fine in a website with a single type of user but how do I segregate data more for reading?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call .stop() in your publish callback function after checking the user role

There is an example here.  https://github.com/alanning/meteor-roles#usage-examples

```
Meteor.publish('secrets', function (group) {
  if (Roles.userIsInRole(this.userId, ['view-secrets','admin'], group)) {

    return Meteor.secrets.find({group: group});

  } else {

    // user not authorized. do not publish secrets
    this.stop();
    return;

  }
});
```

I found this answer after quite a bit of googling.  Hopefully this helps other people.  I still find it odd that you can't just define a read property on allow or deny and achieve the same behavior.

Comment: an alternative is to return an empty list of cursors as `[]`

Answer (score 0):

My answer is for deny read operations on collections:

There is no official solution for this AFAIK,but I think there is a community package for that

try

```
meteor add matb33:collection-hooks
```

link to the package on atmosphere https://atmospherejs.com/matb33/collection-hooks

From the page

> Extends Mongo.Collection with before/after hooks for
>   insert/update/remove/find/find

Copy pasted some example codes from github

```
.before.find(userId, selector, options)
.after.find(userId, selector, options, cursor)
.before.findOne(userId, selector, options)
.after.findOne(userId, selector, options, doc)
```